# Azure Runbook load .Net assembly for application insight

Tags: powershell, azure, automation, runbook

I have requirement where I want to write some metrics to the application insight for monitoring a service at a regular interval.

I though that I would write this PowerShell script and schedule it accordingly.

```
Write-Output "Script Start"
$PSScriptRoot = Get-Location
$AI = "$PSScriptRoot\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll"
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$AI")
$InstrumentationKey = ""
$TelClient = New-Object "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient"
$TelClient.InstrumentationKey = $InstrumentationKey

$TrackMetric = New-Object "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.MetricTelemetry"
$TrackMetric.Name = "PowershellTest"
$TrackMetric.Value = Get-Random -Minimum:1 -Maximum:100

$TelClient.TrackMetric($TrackMetric)
$TelClient.Flush()

Write-Output "Script End  $TrackMetric.Value"
```

This PowerShell Script works, but after I moving that script to Runbook it is no longer working.

So, here is the issue.
I am not able to load the ApplicationInsight DLL inside the Runbook.

Any idea how to do that?

### Exception Details

```
Exception calling "LoadFile" with "1" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 
0x80070002)"
```

Thanks
Siraj

Comment: Please post the actual error code you are receiving, when attempting to run this from `Runbook`.

Answer (score 1):

Try following path for the assembly
"C:\Modules\Global\Azure\Compute\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll"

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in loading the DLL file. The Runbook is not able to find the file in this line:

```
$AI = "$PSScriptRoot\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll"
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$AI")
```

When you run a Runbook via Azure Automation, you don't have access to the local path as you normally do on a local machine or on premise. In Azure Automation, modules are placed in "**C:\Modules**".

Instead, use below code snippet, after you have uploaded the dll file:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Modules\Azure\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll")
```

Closest Related Reference: [Referencing DLL](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/45251bdb-bb20-488c-a428-3ee1094fd568/referencing-microsoftwindowsazurestoragedll-and-creating-cloud-blob-client-using?forum=azureautomation)

Comment: According to this answer from the Azure Automation team http://stackoverflow.com/a/43380852/892770 they recommend using Add-Type instead of Assembly.LoadFrom()