# How to log from Automation account to Application Insights in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-powershell, azure-runbook

I am using **Azure Automation** account to copy my production database to staging. I also do a lot of custom stuff with this copied db + I do some migration stuff with Azure Storage accounts. **To sum up, my 'master' runbook calls another runbooks and all the workflow is quite big so I would like to log every step.**

**Is there any way to use Application Insights for this purpose?** If you know any other possible solutions let me know! I'm looking for the most simple and smart solution.

I found this module https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.applicationinsights/?view=azurermps-6.13.0
But it seems like there are no cmdlets to actually 'log' something.

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
New-AzureRmApplicationInsightsLog -Name "myAppInsights" -LogText "Step 1. Start copying db"
```

Comment: without import app insights dll, you can write powershell script as per this [doc](http://apmtips.com/blog/2017/03/27/oneliner-to-send-event-to-application-insights/) to send data to app insights, but it's a little complex.

Comment: I do not mind to import App Insights dll and I actually tried to but I never succeded in it. I tried all options listed here  https://vnextengineer.azurewebsites.net/powershell-application-insights/ and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870749/azure-runbook-load-net-assembly-for-application-insight and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265741/azure-automation-powershell-runbook-silently-fails-to-loadassembly/43380852#43380852

But I always get an error that the path is invalid. It works all right if I do it on my laptop but when I do it in Azure runbook it fails

Comment: If you can import module in your automation account, you can see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume you can get the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll`. If you don't know how to get it, please let me know.

Then follow the steps below:

1. Put the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll` to a zip file (you can right click the `.dll` file → send to → Compressed (zipped) folder), then you get a zip file named `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.zip`
2. Nav to azure portal → your automation account → Modules → Add a module: upload the zip file in step 1.

   **Note:** this may take a few minutes, when you see the status is available for Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, then it's ok.

   [image]
3. After the module is imported, the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll` is located at this location in azure: `"C:\Modules\User\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll"`
4. Write your code in runbook to send telemetry data to application insights:

   ```
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Modules\User\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll"

    $InstrumentationKey = "xxxx"
    $TelClient = New-Object "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient"
    $TelClient.InstrumentationKey = $InstrumentationKey

    $TelClient.TrackEvent("PowerShell rocks!")
    $TelClient.Flush()

    write-output "ok it is finished."
   ```
5. Check if you can see the data in application insights:

   [image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try and will let you know how it goes!

Comment: @SofiaBo, just wanna know that have you verified it?

Comment: I had another work assignments during the previous days but today I'm going to try implementing it. I'll let you now right away!

Comment: I finally was able to try this out! Unfortunately, something definitely went wrong. I also put the code you listed above in InlineScript{...} because I was getting errors. But when I went to application insights I was not able to see any logs ...

Comment: Oh, wait! It worked, but with a quite big delay...I mean, the timestamp is accurate but I was not able to see it in logs for another 4-5 mins

Comment: @SofiaBo, the delay is by design. The telemetry data is not sent immediately, and the server also needs time to aggregate the data.

Comment: That's ok as far as the timestamp is accurate.

Comment: @IvanGlasenberg When I run this code after importing the applicationinsights dll, within runbook getting this error
Failed
The script in the Workflow Script activity 'Code' is invalid: Could not find type Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient. Load the type(s) and try again.; This type of assignment is not supported. Only variable names (i.e.: $variable) may be used as the target of an assignment statement.; Method invocation is not supported in a Windows PowerShell Workflow. To use .NET scripting, place your commands in an inline script: InlineScript { <commands> }.;
Is the above c

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this?

```
$workspaceId = (Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsWorkspace -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupLA -Name $WorkspaceName).ResourceId

Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $automationAccountId -WorkspaceId $workspaceId -Enabled $true
```

Basically you just configure your entire automation account to use the loganalytics workspace.
You don't do the logging from within the runbook as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you! Is it suitable for tracking the runbooks' workflow? If one of the runbooks that I call from a 'master' runbook throws exception will it be shown there?

Comment: I tried this out and... I actually could not do this with a Free Trial subscription. Well, I'm still looking for a way to log something from runbook to Application Insights. This one is quite close to what I'm looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039586/azure-automation-logging-to-application-insight

But I still wanna be able to run it fully in cloud without having to download anything to my local computer

Comment: As for the exception of other runbooks; Yes, so long as they are in the same automation account. Unfortunate you've got a free subscription though. I don't have anything else to provide you with in that case, except for my thoughts on what you found. I believe you could use a storage account to put the file on that you need. Then possibly use it from there? Automation can have access to Azure services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker